# Azure pipeline - trigger on feature branch

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-triggers

My azure-pipeline.yml is defined like this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - develop

steps:
-task1
-task2
-task3
```

On each push to develop branch the pipeline is triggered - as expected.
I want to trigger the same pipeline on the feature branch.

I created the new branch from develop branch. The name is *featureBranch*.
I edited azure-pipeline.yml to look like this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
     - master
     - develop
     - featureBranch

steps:
-task1
-task2
-task3
```

When I push the code to *featureBranch* the pipeline will not trigger.  I have tried also this but without success:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

A common error scenario is that there are UI Settings which override your YAML-Settings. You can check that in ADO-UI under Pipelines -> the "three dots" -> Triggers.
Also try to include filepaths to further test your scenario:

```
> trigger: 
>   paths:
>    include: *
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with vollmer.io. You could edit this yaml pipeline and check its Triggers settings.
[image]

If there are UI trigger settings which override your yaml trigger settings.
[image]

In addition, if you want to trigger this pipeline when there are pushes to all branches, the following syntax should work.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include: 
    - /*
```

See: [CI triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) for more details.

Comment: Hi user3590094, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.